# hiberfil.sys гибернация

Tags: windows

После пробуждения система очищает hiberfil.sys или помечает его как уже использованный?

Comment: Пожалуйста приведите минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример


 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: из вашего вопроса не понятно что вы хотели сделать, что получилось, и как вы пытались это "что-то" сделать

Comment: компьютер был в гибернации, потом после пробуждения windows очищает файл hiberfil.sys?

Comment: насколько мне известно этот файл не очищаеться

Comment: @Selasi, изменяется системой после гибернации?

Comment: насчет изменяется ли или нет я точно уже не скажу

Comment: но вы можете после гибернации проверить дату когда файл последний раз изменялся

Comment: @Selasi, ну файл там изменятся после запуска компьютера да

Answer (score 0):

В файл **hiberfil.sys** система сбрасывает всё содержимое ОЗУ в момент, когда уходит в сон. После пробуждения файл не очищается и так-же занимает место на диске. Это проблема, когда на системном разделе остаётся мало пространства, а оперативки 8 и более гигабайт. По этой причине, этот файл советуют вообще удалить, предварительно отключив в свойствах менеджера питания опцию "Сон". Для этого в ком.строке достаточно ввести: `powercfg -h off`

Comment: а можно как-то ещё раз запустить гибернацию туже самую второй раз?

Comment: Вроде нет такой опции. Не понятно зачем, но если сильно приспичит, то наверное можно написать свой драйвер, который через менеджер памяти/питания добавит такой функционал.

Comment: ну так можно повторно гибернацию запустить или как? ту же самую. может у вас есть возмоюность проверить?

Comment: `может у вас есть возмоюность проверить?` - нет такой возможности, т.к. у меня этот файл удалён.